# Unable to locate package jupiter

Tags: package-management, jupiter, locate

I'm trying to install jupiter to maintain the heat in my laptop. However, when I use the following:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install jupiter

I get this error:

E: Unable to locate package jupiter

How to solve this ? is there any alternative to maintain the heat ?

Answer (score 0):

The package `jupiter` is no longer available:

From the ppa page on launchpad, 
[Jupiter ppa - WebUpd8 team](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/jupiter):

```
PPA description

Jupiter has been discontinued!
```

The ppa has packages of `jupiter` [up to Raring](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/jupiter/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=&field.series_filter=), but all in status "Deleted" or "Superseded".